# angular 5 conditionally validate field based on another field's value

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-validation

How to conditionally validate a field based on another field's value? Here's what i've tried but it seems not to work

```
this.PDform = _formbuilder.group({
    [...]
    'intlNumber': ['',this.nationality == 'Abroad' ? Validators.compose([Validators.pattern(this.phoneNumberExp), Validators.maxLength(14), Validators.minLength(11), Validators.required]) : Validators ]
    [...]
})
```

Comment: Is `this.nationality` supposed to be another form control? or?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional validation in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137545/conditional-validation-in-angular-2)

Comment: For multiple property validation, it may be better to use one validator, that triggers whenever any input will change in that group of properties. There is a way to do this by grouping those properties in a sub form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 4 form validation on multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47347448/angular-4-form-validation-on-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can change the validators for a form control when the value of another form control changes by subscribing to the `valueChanges` observable provided by the form control instance:

```
const control1 = <FormControl>this.form.get('control1');
const control2 = <FormControl>this.form.get('control2');

control1.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
  if (value === 'first-condition') {
    control2.setValidators([Validators.required, ...])
  }
  else {
    control2.setValidators(null);
  }

  control2.updateValueAndValidity();
});
```

This is a contrived example, but the pattern can be adapted for your use case. Don't forget to assign the subscription to your view model and unsubscribe when your control is destroyed.

Here's a StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/conditional-validation

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, it seems not to be working. I got this error in the console `Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of null`. How do i fix it please

Comment: When are you instantiating your form?

Comment: Instantiated on `ngOnInit()`

Comment: You can put this code directly after you initialize your form.

Comment: Tried  setting it in `ngAfterViewInit()` and it returns same

Comment: I will try to find some time to add a working StackBlitz for you. I use this pattern all the time.

Comment: for some reasons i do not know, i'm still getting the error `Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of null` and everything is right in stackblitz. Angular 5

Comment: the valueChanges subscription is on the specific FormControl instance. Make sure that the .get() statement like you see in the StackBlitz matches the exact control in your form group. You can use dot syntax to access nested controls.

Comment: I was finally able to get it to work. I had to set the condition in a (selectionChange) method in mat-select element. Thanks!!!

Comment: this bug in angular 14. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21109